# Events created via API are not listed in printing

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have created one google calendar with my gmail account and I want to display that calendar in my website.

All Events related to that calender's are inserted via google calendar API using .Net Library.

It shows all events in website.but when i click on print and all events are not display in print preview.

Is there any parameter missing while calling Insert Event  API?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/55624282/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem with events created in a Chrome Extension. I'll spare you the code for the token, but I think it's enough that the event is created without any problems, yet refuses to print.

Desired behaviour: create event that can be printed.
Specific Error: event is created, but can not be printed.
Code:

```
var copyInit = {
                            'method': 'POST',
                            'async': true,
                            'headers': {
                                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Items.access_token,
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
                            'contentType': 'json',
                            'body': dataJson
                        };
```

dataJson:

```
"{"start":{"date":"2019-04-22"},"end":{"date":"2019-04-22"},"summary":"test"}"
```

API Call:

```
            var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calId + '/events?key=AIzaSyDfX9-blah9KoxzvGu3IzA1zu0oDQ-cJfw';
        fetch(url, copyInit)
```

After much head scratching it turns out that although the Google Calendar API allows you to create all day events using the same start date and end date for all day events (using YYYY-MM-DD), such events can not be printed, and when shared will have an end date previous to the start date...

The solution is to use the following day as the end date for all day events:

```
"{"start":{"date":"2019-04-22"},"end":{"date":"2019-04-23"},"summary":"works!"}"
```