# How to fix problem with all day events not visible on Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

In some cases, Google calendar does not correctly show all day events. How do we fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The solution mentioned across this and other questions is as follows:

When creating and all day event - instead of having the same start and end date, you should now have the end date as the following day.

i.e. instead of Start Date :2019-06-05 and End Date: 2019-06-05, the end date should be 2019-06-06

This can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55851521/901666

Comment: It was working fine (with the same day) until few days ago, but now Google agenda android app doesn't display the events wiith same date... (but it's ok on the PC) Need to change my code adding 24h to my end event's date (still 00h00 and UTC). Now working fine. Thank you Ben for your explaination, and thank you Google to communicate when changing such important rules !

Answer (score 1):

First a little background on the issue and then the fix (skip to bottom if you just want the fix).

This issue seems somewhat "random" in that it effects some accounts and not others (perhaps because Google is testing new "features" on a random subset of users before rolling out).

The way you can check if you are a victim of this issue is if there is an all day calendar event which is not visible in your usual Google calendar desktop view but it **DOES** show up if you search for it. The fact that you find it on search but do not see it on regular view demonstrates it is a bug.

In my investigation, it seems like this bug is more likely to show up for all day events created with the Google Calendar API than those created manually but that may just be particular to my setup.

**How to Fix:**

I wasn't able to figure out a perfect fix but if you go to the upper right of the screen for the Google Calendar view on a desktop, there is a dropdown which usually defaults to "Day" or "Week". You can click on this and select "Schedule" and then it will display all your events in a list and make them visible.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing the same issue, and found this fix:

[Events created via API are not listed in printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624282/events-created-via-api-are-not-listed-in-printing/55851521#55851521)

Just tried it and it worked for me! TLDR is that end date needs to be the day following the start date now.

Seems Google is making some changes to the api - I just had the docs for calendar events open in two separate tabs, same exact URL but with some subtle differences in the text -- specifically in the descriptions of start and end dates of all day events.