# Google calendar php API all day events missing/invisible for some users

Tags: php, events, calendar, google-calendar-api

Over the last few days some of our users (not all) have been unable to see all day calendar events that were created via the google api.

They CAN see them on either their phone calendar, or when viewing inbox and clicking the right hand calendar icon, or selecting to view 'Schedule' instead of 'Day' or 'Week'

Google has no explanation.

Edit:

Here is my answer..

> The solution mentioned across this and other questions is as follows:
>
> When creating and all day event - instead of having the same start and
>   end date, you should now have the end date as the following day.
>
> i.e. instead of Start Date :2019-06-05 and End Date: 2019-06-05, the
>   end date should be 2019-06-06
>
> This can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55851521/901666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating and all day event - instead of having the same start and end date, you should now have the end date as the following day.

i.e. instead of Start Date :2019-06-05 and End Date: 2019-06-05, the end date should be 2019-06-06

This can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55851521/901666